# Стандартные права на папки и файлы Drupal 7

Tags: linux, drupal, permissions

слетели права на все файлы и папки, пришлось восстанавливать.
в бэкапе посмотрел - на все папки права 755, на все файлы 644, кроме:
папки /sites/default и файла /sites/default/settings.php - на них были изначально права 555.
выполнил:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod 555 './sites/default'
chmod 755 './sites/default/files'
chmod 555 './sites/default/settings.php'
```

это нормально или надо что-то подправить?
спасибо.

update: поменял на 444 права для './sites/default/settings.php' в соответствие с https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/install/step-3-create-settingsphp-and-the-files-directory - так правильнее будет?

Comment: да, все верно, права могут быть разные, это зависит от специфики  проекта. Иногда нужно и больше давать правна директорию в которой лежат features. А так нужно давать 444 на settings.php и здесь `admin/config/media/file-system` проверить нет ли каких то сообщений о правах

Comment: большое спасибо! а почему были права 555 на settings.php? это опасно или не очень?